# Jhipster docker image is not working and in logs it is giving multiple warning related to plugin

Tags: java, docker, jhipster, jib, maven-jib

I am using latest Jhipster version 7.0.1 and java version 'Adoptopenjdk:11.0.11'.
Trying to dockerize generated project but every time image is created in docker but is is not accessible. Unable to up created server image.

Getting below logs in console while creating docker image:

using cmd:
"mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild -Dmaven.test.skip=true"

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.cockpit:cockpit-server >---------------------
[INFO] Building Cockpit Server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (default-resources) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-dependencyConvergence) @ cockpit-server ---
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.15.2
    +-org.testcontainers:jdbc:1.15.2
      +-org.testcontainers:database-commons:1.15.2
        +-org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.2
          +-org.rnorth.visible-assertions:visible-assertions:2.1.2
            +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.15.2
    +-org.testcontainers:jdbc:1.15.2
      +-org.testcontainers:database-commons:1.15.2
        +-org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.2
          +-com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-zerodep:3.2.7
            +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.5.2.Final paths to dependency are:
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:2.4.4
    +-io.undertow:undertow-core:2.2.5.Final
      +-org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.8.0.Final
        +-org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.5.2.Final
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:2.4.4
    +-io.undertow:undertow-core:2.2.5.Final
      +-org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.8.0.Final
        +-org.wildfly.client:wildfly-client-config:1.0.1.Final
          +-org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.2.0.Final

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.4
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.4
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1
        +-org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.1
          +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.4
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.4
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine:0.17.0
    +-com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine-api:0.17.0
      +-org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.1
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:problem-violations:0.26.2
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:problem-spring-common:0.26.2
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.cockpit:cockpit-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:faux-pas:0.8.0
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] argLine set to "-javaagent:C:\\Users\\rswami\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.6\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\cockpit_jhipster\\Updated Code\\target\\jacoco.exec" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:4.0.4:revision (default) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-info (default) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (post-unit-test) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\cockpit_jhipster\Updated Code\target\cockpit-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:repackage (default) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent-integration (pre-integration-tests) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] argLine set to "-javaagent:C:\\Users\\rswami\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.6\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\cockpit_jhipster\\Updated Code\\target\\jacoco-it.exec" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (integration-test) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report-integration (post-integration-tests) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.2:check (default) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] You have 0 Checkstyle violations.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) @ cockpit-server ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jib-maven-plugin:2.8.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) @ cockpit-server ---
[WARNING] Setting image creation time to current time; your image may not be reproducible.
[INFO]
[INFO] Containerizing application to Docker daemon as cockpitserver...
[WARNING] Base image 'adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
[INFO] The base image requires auth. Trying again for adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9...
[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry-1.docker.io
[WARNING]
Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry.hub.docker.com
[WARNING]
Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: index.docker.io
[WARNING]
Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: docker.io
[WARNING]
Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[INFO] Using base image with digest: sha256:3f83314c35d31106343aed1011cdc6d50632f52746242ea1f0142b3b8db67944
[INFO]
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [bash, -c, /entrypoint.sh]
[INFO]
[INFO] Built image to Docker daemon as cockpitserver
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [==============================] 100.0% complete
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45.826 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-28T13:17:42+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As error says: the base image for adoptopenjdk requires authentication, maybe you are behind a corporate firewall. Have you tried to pull this image with `docker pull`? Which version of docker are you running?

Comment: I'm getting this same error when using OpenJDK 11.0.11, but without the "base image requires auth". It just fails when "enforcing releasability", then when the app launches it immediately gives a "Connection refused" error on the service (I assume it's because the service wasn't launched due to the releasability errors).

Answer (score 1):

The warning is harmless, as long as Jib works. Indeed, I see it worked:

```
Built image to Docker daemon as cockpitserver
```

You've successfully built an image, and if you do `docker images`, your Docker daemon will list `cockpitserver`. That's the image you built.